# Get all parents of an element in nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following data stored in a variable:

```
let categories = [
    {
        name: "a",
        nodes: [
            {
                name: "aa",
                nodes: [
                    {
                        name: "aaa"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "ab",
            },
            {
                name: "ac",
            },
            {
                name: "ad",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "b",
        nodes: [
            {
                name: "ba",
            },
            {
                name: "bb",
            },
            {
                name: "bc",
            },
            {
                name: "bd",
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

And I have the following recursive function which accepts the **categories** variable and **name**.

```
function getCategoryParents(categories, name) {
    for (let index = 0; index < categories.length; index++) {
        const category = categories[index];
        if (category.name === name) {
        }
        if (category.nodes && category.nodes.length) {
            category.nodes.forEach(cat => this.getCategoryParents([cat], name));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to return an array of names containing the name in the parameter and the parents of that name.

For example if I called `getCategoryParents(categories, "aaa")` it should returns [**"a"**, **"aa"**, **"aaa"**]. because **aa** is the parent of **aaa** and **a** is the parent of **aa**.

I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweaked your function so it would actually return some values when it finds the matches :

```js
function getCategoryParents(arr, name) {
  for (let child of arr) {
    if (child.name === name) {
      return name;
    } else if (child.nodes.length > 0) {
      var x = getCategoryParents(child.nodes, name);

      if (x) return Array.isArray(x) ? [child.name, ...x] : [child.name, x];
    }
  }
}

let categories = [
  {
    name: "a",
    nodes: [
      {
        name: "aa",
        nodes: [
          {
            name: "aaa"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "ab"
      },
      {
        name: "ac"
      },
      {
        name: "ad"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    nodes: [
      {
        name: "ba"
      },
      {
        name: "bb"
      },
      {
        name: "bc"
      },
      {
        name: "bd"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const result = getCategoryParents(categories, "aaa");
console.log(result); // ["a", "aa", "aaa"]
```

Comment: [child.name, x].flat is not a function. is there any other supported function i can use instead of flat ?

Comment: @Ayoubk , oh, you're using node ? i updated the answer